# Is it safe to include localhost into your connect-src for CSP?

Tags: browser-sync, content-security-policy

I'm adding content security policy via the meta tag, and it seems I am being blocked for local development tools (ex, browser sync with `ws://localhost:9000/`). I want to add it to the `connect-src`, but I am unsure of the implications this might have. Is it safe?